# MAP C++ using itr.first->second VS itr->second

Tags: c++

In http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/, I am confused with the reasoning of doing `ret.first->second` or `it->second` to access the 2nd value.  Why was it necessary to do `.first->second` if you can do it with just `->second`?

```cpp
// map::insert (C++98)
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main ()
{
  std::map<char,int> mymap;
  std::pair<std::map<char,int>::iterator,bool> ret;
  ret = mymap.insert ( std::pair<char,int>('z',500) );
  if (ret.second==false) {
    std::cout << "element 'z' already existed";
    std::cout << " with a value of " << ret.first->second << '\n';
  }

  // showing contents:
  std::cout << "mymap contains:\n";
  for (std::map<char,int>::iterator it=mymap.begin(); it!=mymap.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each `std::map` element is stored as a `std::pair` containing its key and value (in the pair's `first` and `second` fields, respectively).

The [`std::map::insert()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) method returns a [`std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) containing:

- a `std::map::iterator` pointing at the `std::map` element for the key which is being inserted.
- a `bool` indicating whether that element has been newly inserted or it already existed in the `std::map`.

When the code calls `ret = mymap.insert(...);`, `ret.first` is the `iterator` and `ret.second` is the `bool`.

Dereferencing a `std::map::iterator` accesses the key/value `std::pair` of the element which the iterator is pointing at.

Thus, since `ret.first` is a `std::map::iterator`, then `ret.first->first` is the element's key and `ret.first->second` is the element's value.

In the subsequent loop, `for (it=mymap.begin(); it!=mymap.end(); ++it)`, `it` is also a `std::map::iterator`, pointing at a different element of the `std::map` on each loop iteration.  Thus, when dereferencing that iterator, `it->first` is the element's key and `it->second` is the element's value.

Answer (score 1):

The variable ret is declared as an object of the class template std::pair

```
std::pair<std::map<char,int>::iterator,bool> ret;
```

To get the iterator in the object you have to write

```
ret.first
```

as for example

```
std::map<char, int>::iterator it = ret.first;
```

Now to get the mapped value using the iterator you have to write the expression

```
it->second
```

So substituting it for its value you will get

```
ret.first->second
```

In this loop

```
  for (it=mymap.begin(); it!=mymap.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << '\n'
```

there is already used an iterator that is not wrapped in an object of the class template std::pair.

Answer (score 1):

Those are two different things.

- When you have an iterator `it`, you need to do `it->second` to (a) dereference it, and (b) get the "second" item of the resulting pair, i.e. the map *value*.
- The result of `insert` (`ret`) is two things: an iterator, and a `bool` telling you whether an insertion actually happened. You need `ret.first` to get the iterator, *then* you apply the logic from above.

In other words, `ret.first` is like `it`. So, `ret.first->second` is like `it->second`.

---

It *does* seem a bit confusing, because `pair`s were used, rather than types with descriptive member names like `iterator`/`wasInserted` and `key`/`value`.

There's an alternate universe out there somewhere in which cplusplus.com's code looks more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
   std::map<char, int> mymap;
   MapInsertionResult ret = mymap.insert(std::pair<char, int>('z',500));
   if (ret.performedInsertion == false)
   {
      std::cout << "element 'z' already existed";
      std::cout << " with a value of " << ret.it->value << '\n';
   }

   // showing contents:
   std::cout << "mymap contains:\n";
   for (auto it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); ++it)
   {
      std::cout << it->key << " => " << it->value << '\n';
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, we do not live in it.

---

By the way, `mymap.emplace('z', 500)` is shorter than your `insert` call, if you can use C++11+.

Comment: The OP did not say he was stuck on C++98.  The example he provided was copy/pasted from cplusplus.com and it was simply written for C++98.